# Group objects with common key in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Multiple objects i have with common keys, am trying to group all duplicated objects and map any extra key exist in any object

Data i have like below

```
var array = [
  { id: 'Staging', cumulative: 16 },
  { id: 'Staging', yeasterday: 16 },
  { id: 'Staging', week: 16 },
  { id: 'Staging', yeasterday: 16 },

  { id: 'Staging1', cumulative: 16 },
  { id: 'Staging1', yeasterday: 16 },
  { id: 'Staging1', week: 16 },
];
```

Expected results, suppose to be below

```
var array = [
  { id: 'Staging', cumulative: 16, month: 16, week: 16, yeasterday: 16 },

  { id: 'Staging1', cumulative: 16, yeasterday: 16, week: 16 },
];
```

Comment: Please, take a read to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It will be nice to see what you have tried and the expected output.

Comment: simple google search https://www.google.com/search?q=group+by+javascript&oq=group+by+javascript&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4591j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 will give you the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most efficient method to groupby on a array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-array-of-objects)

Comment: Why is `yeasterday ` repeated twice for the first object of the result array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by with Vanilla JavaScript (without any clunky external libraries such as Lodash). My approach will require you to use Array.reduce(), together with [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which is one of ES6's features. Then, we can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (or [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)) to transform the `Iterator` object (which contains the values of each element from the `Map` object) into an array to obtain the format similar to the required output as stated on the question.

```js
const arr = [ {id: "Staging", cumulative: 16}, {id: "Staging", yeasterday: 16}, {id: "Staging", week: 16}, {id: "Staging", yeasterday: 16},
{id: "Staging1", cumulative: 16}, {id: "Staging1", yeasterday: 16}, {id: "Staging1", week: 16}
]

const iteratorMap = arr.reduce((entry, e) => entry.set(e['id'], {...entry.get(e['id'])||{}, ...e}), new Map()).values();

const result = [...iteratorMap];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce` like so:

```js
var array = [{
  id: "Staging",
  cumulative: 16
}, {
  id: "Staging",
  yeasterday: 16
}, {
  id: "Staging",
  week: 16
}, {
  id: "Staging",
  yeasterday: 16
}, {
  id: "Staging1",
  cumulative: 16
}, {
  id: "Staging1",
  yeasterday: 16
}, {
  id: "Staging1",
  week: 16
}]

var newArray = array.reduce((acc, { id, ...rest }) => {
  acc[id] = { ...(acc[id] || {}), ...rest };
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) library and obtain the resutls

```
var result = _.chain(array)
              .groupBy('id')
              .map((val) => _.reduce(val, (result, value) => _.merge(result, value), {}))
              .value()
```